# Mathern Covariance funcion

Tags: covariance, bessel-functions

From an article, they use Matern Covariance function : $$C_v (d)=\frac{1}{2^{\nu-1}\Gamma(\nu)}(\frac{d}{\phi})^\nu\kappa_\nu(\frac{d}{\phi})$$ with $\phi, \nu>0$ and $\kappa_\nu$ a modified Bessel function of order $\nu$.
I have looked this up on google and found Bessel function has two kinds. But there is not anything about subscript $\nu$ of the Bessel function. Also, I googled '[Mathern Covariance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function)' on wiki. It says, $\rho$ and $\nu$ are just non-negative parameters of the covariance. I want to know what the meanings are.

> In short, I want to know the parameters of Matern Covariance function.
>   How do they work, what do they mean? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think $\nu$ is called the smoothness parameter and $\phi$ is called the scale parameter. The names are quite suggestive, don't you think?

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri Thank you for your comment. In my article, the author used $\nu=2$ as an assumption. I think $\nu=2$ is a common default. What does the $\nu=2$ means?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mat%C3%A9rn_covariance_function .  It explains the connection between $\nu$ with the smoothness of paths.

Comment: @ArinChaudhuri Yes. But what about $\nu=2$?